# Use a TLD as a Root domain in AD server

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server

A lot of companies use their own Top Level Domain Names in their internal networks for resolving internal services. As an example, I would mention the `.intel` TLD.

I'm doing something similar in my homelab. For the purposes of this post, let it be `.example`.

I would like to set up an Active Directory server for user authentication and DNS management. Here's my problem: when I want to promote the Windows Server to a Domain Controller, it asks for a Root forest domain. When I type in `example`, the following error occurs:

```
Verification of forest name failed. The DNS name "example"
proposed for this Active Directory domain consists of single label.
DNS domain names should be unique and fully qualified,
consisting of one or more labels separated by a period ("."),
followed by a top level domain.
```

Screenshot of Windows error:
[image: Screenshot of Windows error]

I have also tried typing in `.example` but the error still persists.

Is there any registry tweak, that I need to make to skip this check?

Comment: Your domain name should be in the form of (prefix.)name.suffix. More information on selecting the root forest domain can be found at microsoft (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/selecting-the-forest-root-domain) including the reason why single label domain names are a no no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a domain name or subdomain name for your Active Directory domain. Microsoft and many others recommend using a subdomain. Using just example or .example is not allowed. The text and example from the link below explains more.

"The AD domain name is NOT the same as the DNS name, but they are linked. AD Domain names are mainly used within AD operations, mostly LDAP queries for AD functionality, while DNS is rather a network level solution for name resolution on IP level (to resolve the machines or application names to IP addresses). Essentially this difference allows you to use a 'internal', private AD domain name and use a public, registered DNS.

For example

AD Domain name: CORP
DNS name: corp.example.org
"

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34981.active-directory-best-practices-for-internal-domain-and-network-names.aspx